# what does the coefficients ring of generalized cohomology defined by the unitary Thom spectrum like?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, cobordism

Let $MU$ be the unitary Thom spectrum, then it gives a generalized cohomology,
 so what is the coefficients  $MU^*(point)$ like? 
Is it just the complex cobordism ring $\Omega_U^*?$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is complex cobordism.  Therefore the coefficient ring is a polynomial ring on a generator in each positive even degree.

Comment: It is also isomorphic to the Lazard ring, a universal one-dimensional formal group law.


Comment: NB: As a *co*homology theory, the generators of the polynomial ring occur in negative cohomological degrees.